# Inner element should be trimmed by outer element border radius

Tags: html, css, rounded-corners

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/QSp2W/5/

As you can see the inner `h1` has a background color which overlaps the rounded corners of the containing `div`. This is sort of fixed if you set a smaller radius on the inner `h1` but this is a hack. (Uncomment the commented CSS to see what I mean.)

#### Version 2 (23, really)

http://jsfiddle.net/QSp2W/23/ but I don't know how to apply the `*` selector to only direct children, not grandchildren.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would give `H1` and `p` the CSS properties instead of the div as below. You could create a class just for borders and apply them to the appropriate element.

http://jsfiddle.net/QSp2W/7/

CSS:

```
div h1
{
    padding: 2px;
    background-color: #ff0000;
    border-top: 2px solid #000000;
    border-left: 2px solid #000000;
    border-right: 2px solid #000000;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    /* Below gets it close but not quite. */
    /*border-radius: 7px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;*/
}

div p
{
    padding: 10px;
    border-left: 2px solid #000000;
    border-right: 2px solid #000000;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

This is with separate border class:
http://jsfiddle.net/QSp2W/9/

Comment: This seems to be the most visually-appealing and flexible solution, here is how I applied it: http://jsfiddle.net/QSp2W/23/ But I'm not sure how to make `*` only apply to the children and not the grandchildren.

Comment: Like this `div > *` http://jsfiddle.net/QSp2W/24/ . This will only select direct children of div.

Answer (score 2):

Adding `overflow: hidden` to the containing `div` effectively gets the background to do what you want, but it seems to overwrite the border! So, not quite perfect... :)

Answer (score 1):

you can do it this way http://jsfiddle.net/yuliantoadi/QSp2W/8/

Comment: +1 Very nice solution - keeps the bounding box CSS in the right place and forces the children to do as expected!

Comment: Simple enough - but if I had a background on the div (http://jsfiddle.net/QSp2W/11/) that won't work. (I realize that wasn't the question, just pointing it out.)

Comment: Also I still need to use the small-border-radius-hack.

Answer (score 0):

The most direct way is to have the `div h1` inherit from the `div`.

So `border-radius: inherit;` instead of setting a radius #.

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/QSp2W/10/

Comment: The reason I set border-radius to 6px in my example is because if you have it set the same as the parent, you get the white spacing between them.

Comment: The other thing you could do is add `background-color` to all the `element`s and `border-bottom-radius` to the `p`.  http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/QSp2W/18/